# When is the last day I can travel to the UK if my visa expires on March 5th?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-expiration

Hello I would like to ask if can I still travel to UK before end of feb? But the problem my visa it's  about to expire in March 5 2019

Answer (score 9):

If your visa is valid you can travel to the UK any time up to the expiry date, but you must leave on or before 5 March 2019.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the UK immigration officer is unlikely to admit someone without a credible plan to leave by the visa's expiration date.  For example, someone who arrives with a return flight booked after the visa's expiration date runs a very high risk of being refused entry altogether.